# Formatted text file reading in c++

Tags: c++

This is the file.

```
R: 10
Steve Abrew 90 80 84 76
David Nag 93 87 90 80
Mike Black
Andrew Van Den 90 88 95 85
Chris Smith 86 74 90
Dennis Dudley 74 76 77 83
Leo Rice 95 75
Fred Flinstone 73 67 78 72
Dave Light 89 71 91 89
Hua Tran Du 81 79 80
```

I want read these from the file and create a variable for characters and another variable for integers separately. But not able to do it..

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(argv[1]);

if(!inFile)
{
cerr<<"Couldn't find the file";
return -1;
}

string data;

getline(inFile,data,'\0');
cout<<data<<"\n";

return 0;
}
```

the output came now same as the file.. But everything is saved in string data.. But now how can i separate names and int from that string?

Much appreciated if you guyz help :)

Comment: Please help use by indenting the code to make it more readable

Comment: Format the file contents. Curretly it is not clear..

Comment: Look into streams and the `<<` operator

Comment: Ok now it is indented... Now can u guyz help?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got the format.

I can tell you how to do it.
Before doing it, Make an int variable called `N`, and a `deque<string>` type container `Characters` and a `deque<deque<int>>` type container `Data`.
(Of course you have to do `#include <deque>`)
(and also `#include <sstream>` and `#include <string>`)

First, input the "R:" part -> `inFile >> temp;`

Second, input how many lines of data will be collected.-> `inFile >> N;`

Third, input the data.

```
for(int i = 0;i<N;i++)
{
    string Fn, Ln;
    inFile >> Fn >> Ln;
    Characters.push_back(Fn+" "+Ln); //name
    string A;
    getline(inFile,A);
    stringstream ss(A);
    int W;
    deque<int> TempData;
    while(ss>>W)
    {
        TempData.push_back(W);
    }
    Data.push_back(TempData);
}
```

Now the names are in the `Characters` container and their data is in the `Data` container!

Comment: Also, I suggest you to edit the format a little because there are also names with three words.

Comment: Bro, is it possible to do it another way? Because i am new to c++ and cant get the deque thing.. :(

Comment: But i did another thing... I took the whole reading into a character array.. Is it possible now to store character into a string and integers into an int from that character array?

Comment: There is a way to filter string and int

Comment: But I'll try that for you!